# Flutter: hide navbar when drawer is open

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I followed [this](https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-case-study-multiple-navigators-with-bottomnavigationbar-90eb6caa6dbf) tutorial on how to create a bottom navbar and it works great apart from the fact that I dont know how to appropriately add a drawer.

Currently my code looks something like this for the screen that holds the navigational bar:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async =>
          !await navigatorKeys[currentTab].currentState.maybePop(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          _buildOffstageNavigator(TabItem.red),
          _buildOffstageNavigator(TabItem.green),
          _buildOffstageNavigator(TabItem.blue),
        ]),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(
          currentTab: currentTab,
          onSelectTab: _selectTab,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And like this for my home screen:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      endDrawer: const NavigationDrawerWidget(),
      body: const _HomePageBody(),
    );
  }
}
```

All of this is functioning, however, the drawer does not hide the navigational bar when its opened. I have thought about placing the drawer instead on the screen that holds the but that introduces more problems than it fixes. Such as the hamburger icon does not appear unless I also add an appbar to the said screen and I only want it to be present on the homepage and not its "subpages" (pages that I can access through the homepage but are not the pages present on the navbar).

My next thought is that I could possibly hide the navbar when the drawer opens and reveal it when the drawer is closed again. But then there is the difficulty of animating in such a way to make it look nice and seems like a long winded solution.

At this point it seems like the navbar is the problem but I have tried redoing it so many times such that the end result would be a bar that is present on all pages (+ subpages) and saves state that it would be unfortunate to change it up again.

I would appreciate any suggestions or links to other projects/tutorials that are doing something similar. Thanks :)

**Edit**

here is a reproducible example, I wipped it up quite quickly so sorry for it being a bit messy

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int pageIndex = 0;

  final pages = [
    const Page(
      title: "page 1",
      drawer: true,
    ),
    const Page(
      title: "page 2",
      drawer: false,
    ),
    const Page(
      title: "page 3",
      drawer: false,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: pages[pageIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        height: 60,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  pageIndex = 0;
                });
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.home_outlined,
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  pageIndex = 1;
                });
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.work_outline_outlined,
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  pageIndex = 2;
                });
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.widgets_outlined,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page({Key? key, required this.title, required this.drawer})
      : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final bool drawer;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      endDrawer: drawer ? const Drawer() : null,
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 45,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a drawer on Home widget and the body widget contains a drawer? Can you provide minimal full widgets.

Comment: Im not entirely sure what you mean with minimal full widgets, but yes currently the drawer is on the HomePage as it provided the best result so far but the body contains a bottom navigation bar

Comment: how about using single scaffold on top widget and more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have added an example that has the same issue as me

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use single scaffold and include your drawer and appBar on 1st scaffold.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  endDrawer: pageIndex == 0 ? const Drawer() : null,
  body: pages[pageIndex],
  appBar: AppBar(),
  bottomNavigationBar: Container(
```

Comment: By doing this I would need to include an appbar in the scaffold, but the pages in my project have different appbars. Also this would mean that the drawer is active in my sub pages so this solution doesnt fit me sadly

Comment: Drawer is not active under the other pages because `pageIndex == 0` and you can have same condition for appBar.

Comment: By sub pages I mean the pages that are not included in the navbar but you can navigate to them from the homepage, for example the homepage has a gallery and you click on an image which redirects you to a new page listing the details of the image with the navbar still present but different appbar. I have no idea how to differentiate between those pages since technically the `pageIndex` is the same for them.

Comment: does that make it a bit more clearer?